# Support mapping

Tags: unity

Hello I'm Trying to implement a quickhull 3d variant as explained in this paper.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5yoggi3lgrucvl/easy%20hull.png?dl=1]

http://www.xbdev.net/misc_demos/demos/convexhull3d/paper.pdf

But It seems that I'm failing at implementing the support mapping algorithm. Now I'm **not** asking about how to do quickhull, I'm asking specifically how to **fix support mapping**

Here is the code I came up with, I'm basically iterating all vectors, find their support points, and try to find which one are in the inner shape (discarded).

```
 foreach (Vector3 v in vertlist) 
  {
   centroid += v;
  }
  centroid /= vertlist.Length;

  Vector3 support = new Vector3();
  float max = float.Epsilon;

  foreach (Vector3 v in vert) 
  {

   Vector3 direction = v - centroid;
   max = float.Epsilon;

   foreach (Vector3 t in vert) 
   {
    Vector3 compared= t - centroid;

    float dot = Vector3.Dot (compared,direction);

    if (dot > max)
    {
     max = dot;
     support = t;
    }
   }

   if (support != v) 
   {
    discard.Add (v);
    print ("discard:"+v);
   }

   if (support == v) 
   {
    print ("self");
   }
  }
```

And this is the visualized result
[image]

The point are clearly not inside the shape, quite the contrary, where did I did it wrong? I don't understand.